# Power BI and MySQL 5.5.34 compatibility

Tags: mysql, windows, powerbi, connector

I would connect Power BI with an glpi database but I think I have a compatibility problem.
I don't know which connector version install.
I tried several releases, but I always have this error message:

```
DataSource.Error : MySQL : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Détails :
    DataSourceKind=MySql
    DataSourcePath=glpi_server01;glpidb
    Message=Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
    ErrorCode=-2147467259`
```

The database release is `5.5.34`.
I tried several connectors but I haven't found a good version.
Someone could help me please? How could I connect?

Comment: Looks like a mysql server problem. Run mysql_upgrade as a command and `CHECK TABLE mysql.proc` as a SQL command. Suggest upgrading to 5.5.62 as a first step and then evaluate the options of moving to a supported MySQL version. Do you have backups of the mysql.proc table?